# jmf wav to mp3 conversion issue

Tags: java, mp3, wav, jmf

I am trying to convert a wav file into mp3 format using the below code. A mp3 file is created but it is blank file without any content. Any ideas what could be causing this.

```
        Format[] FORMATS = new Format[] { new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.LINEAR) };
        String srcFilePath = "C:" + File.separator + "Users"
                + File.separator + "vkiran" + File.separator + "Desktop"
                + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "4a714ea2.wav";
        String mp3FilePath = "C:" + File.separator + "Users"
                + File.separator + "vkiran" + File.separator + "Desktop"
                + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "4a714ea2.mp3";
        File srcFile = new File(srcFilePath);
        File destFile = new File(mp3FilePath);

        MediaLocator source = new MediaLocator(srcFile.toURL());

        DataSource d = Manager.createDataSource(source);

        ContentDescriptor cd = new ContentDescriptor(
                FileTypeDescriptor.MPEG_AUDIO);

        Processor p = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(new ProcessorModel(d,
                FORMATS, cd));

        p.configure();

        System.out.println((p.getDuration()).getSeconds());

        MediaLocator destination = new MediaLocator(destFile.toURL());
        DataSource ds = p.getDataOutput();
        DataSink sink = Manager.createDataSink(p.getDataOutput(),
                destination);
        sink.open();
        sink.start();

        sink.stop();
        sink.close();

        p.stop();
        p.close();
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your issue but I can't find a wav file that gets past `Processor p = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(new ProcessorModel(d, FORMATS, cd));`

Comment: JMF does not provide functionality to **encode** to MP3, but just to do the opposite and **decode** the resulting file.

Comment: If I use JMStudio, I am able to export the same file from WAV to mp3 format. I am assuming JMStudio uses JMF in the back ground. So if JMStudio is able to do it, I thought I will be able to do it using JMF.

Comment: @JasonSperske The format I tried to convert is PCM Audio, 8000Hz  64 kb/s (1 chnl)

Comment: For my site (http://sndtst.com) I just passed the wav file to lame.exe with Apache Commons.Exec